# $X$ a random variable with $ X = \sum_{i}\alpha_iI_{B_i}, \; \alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ a random variable with $$ X = \sum_{i}\alpha_iI_{B_i}, \; \alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}.$$ $B_i$ is finite partition and they are measurable.
Show that X is then $\mathcal{G-}$ measurable.
And then the other side. If $X$ is a random variable, that is $\mathcal{G-}$ measurable, then $X$ has the form: $X = \sum_{i}\alpha_iI_{B_i}, \; \alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}. $

Random variable $X : Ω → \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{G-}$ measurable, iff
for all $a ∈ \mathbb{R}:$
$$\{X ≤ a\} = X^{−1}((−∞, a]) ∈ \mathcal{G}.$$

**My Approach:**

$$ I_{B_i} \Leftrightarrow \chi_{B_i} = \left\{\begin{matrix} 1, \; x\in B_i
 & \\ 0, \; x\notin B_i
 & 
\end{matrix}\right. 
\Rightarrow \begin{matrix} \chi_{B_i}^{-1}(\{1\})=B_i \in 2^{\Omega}
 & \\ \chi_{B_i}^{-1}(\{0\})=B_i^c\in 2^{\Omega}
 & 
\end{matrix} \Rightarrow \chi(B_i) \;\:\, \mathcal{G-} mesurable$$

And since a linear combination of measurable is also measurable, then we that $X$ is measurable.

**My Problem:**
I have only proved one side, and I am not sure if it is correct. I would be helpful for any kind of input for my first solution and help with the other direction.

Comment: And is the index set of your sum finite? Are the $B_i$ measurable?

Comment: What is $\mathcal G$? Is it a $\sigma$-Algebra? And is $I_{B_i} = \chi_{B_i}$? I don't understand what you mean by $I_{B_i} \iff \chi_{B_i}$.

Comment: $B_i$ sets are measurable, index is finite, $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(B_i : I)$.

Comment: @variableXYZ Please edit this vital information into your question.